# Attribute android:gravity is not allowed here

Tags: android, xml, flutter

I was running a Flutter app, in that i was trying to remove the white screen when the app is initialized upon start up, so just went into **android=>app=>src=>main=>res=>drawable=>launch_background.xml**, there I edited the code but was unable to get the **gravity attribute** as i was getting an error as `Attribute android:gravity is not allowed here`. I did even try **Invalidate Caches/Restart** and **minSdkVersion 21**. The image does is showing up if i remove the `android:gravity` attribute

````
<item>
    <bitmap
       android:gravity="center"
       android:src="@mipmap/launcher_icon" />
</item>
```[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WdVm.png
````

Comment: minSdkVersion 23

Comment: Nope still the same issue

Comment: also compileSdkVersion must be at least 29

Comment: Yes it is, but still having the same issue